# Why can't TypeScript assert that a chain of nullable values is all non-null at the same time?

Tags: typescript, null

I have a chain of nullable values that I'd like to assert is non-null in a single line.

It seems to me that if TS knows that `availablePackages` is non-null then the whole chain is definitely non-null.  But I still get an error if I write further code assuming `offerings` is non-null here.  Is that expected behavior somehow?  the `offerings` reference could not have changed in the meantime and it had to be non-null for the previous call to work.

```
export function hasValue<T>(value: T): value is NonNullable<T> {
  return value !== undefined && value !== null;
}

// ...

if (!hasValue(offerings?.current?.availablePackages)) {
  return;
}

offerings.current.availablePackages.length < 1; // ERROR, offerings may be null
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: TS does not do inference between different pieces of code because it apparently it would slow down compilation *a lot*.

Comment: @VLAZ This is not true at all. The check itself would be rather simple and not at all expensive. Check my answer for the real reason.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß I disagree that I lied or misinformed: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFMOcBciDeiBGAhgE4D82AzlMTGAOaIC+AlNgG5wwAmuAUIgMQQEVRDAoAxQgBsKAT0QBeRAEJ0cAHRFiAbn6CYwRCnFTZc5omIBTKCGJg9+geq0kN06-SgALPY14gA). In general, the CFA employed by TS does not go through inferences, only direct checks are respected. *Logically*, the code in OP should work - we as programmers can look at it and confirm. There are no cases where the `if` will *not* pass and `offerings` would be `null`. TS does not deduce this, however.

Comment: hmh... interesting, didn't catch that. So it's a combination of both answers. The references aren't respected anyway, so using optional chaining won't work with that in the first place.
This seems odd though, there must be a technical reason on how JavaScript works for this oddity. My guess would be that you cannot ensure that the object hasn't been altered, since it's just a reference.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß "*there must be a technical reason on how JavaScript works for this oddity*" JavaScript is not related at all. It's the TS compiler that does the analysis and decide what the supposed state would be when executing some code. It can detect constant conditions (e.g., `const bool` somewhere and then `if (bool)` will always produce the same effect), dead code (e.g., code after `return`), etc. "*you cannot ensure that the object hasn't been altered, since it's just a reference*" sometimes this is the case if you go across function boundaries. However, this is straight code -

Comment: @JohannesKlauß there is no multithreading happening. The object cannot change between two lines. As I said, the analysis becomes expensive if it starts being done transitively and/or correlated with previous pieces of code. [Some discussion here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998). In theory you *can* deduce the nullity. We as programmers can definitely do it. It's just that TS does not.

Comment: I read over all the answers and links but would still like this case to work haha.  It seems a trivial inference at least that if a.b.c is non-null (all simple values), then on the very next line a, b, and c are all guaranteed to be non-null.  This should not rely on any JS transpilation details.  I read over the "some discussion" from @VLAZ but tbh none of it seems totally applicable here because there's no chance at all for anything to modify this state; and anyway if "possible state change" were the issue that would apply just as much to the leaf (c) as to the parents (a and b).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are checking for a property that itself is accessed in a safe guard way using optional chaining.

To illustrate the problem I created this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gZnCAnAlgOwOYGcoF4oDeAUFFAMYCuSSEawA-AFyEmlQCGAbuygDbsAjXhAAK7MgGt2GCFiYc0IANoBdANysAvkU0aiRCAA8wAeyTAocCmjLAUJtFAAW7LADV2vChAA8AFQA+AApuLwhmPwBKZlDvKBQcADkHRIpefiFfQJZSGmAqR1joAEJcfGsAEwg4dAgKqAAyBqgiqFL8NDTeDW0iAHo+qAA6Ef1XEBtLa1t7R2BZYCDInPIHLAsTBGR0bGZ4RFRMHHx2AHceCyCzi8sIYDInIIByJ2BgMCxGAaN2AFswYRDMgmX5PSKRIYAKywDiWelIKDgUCCmwOO2OHS6UAAPtioKjtkcgVQaHQ8Jj0ji8QTDthidRaMAhlweBlhGJJNJZOSoJ10stiGwoHkChpSL0EUigsUXO5PN4UVtaXJ6aSGMzuHxBOzxFIZFhwStcndRVp9KwaejVYyNaztaJdVysENhJhgE4oD4oABGHpEIA)

It's important to remember that TypeScript compiles down to JavaScript and with that we sometimes forget some small but important things.

I added a second to your code and add a fetch to illustrate the unknown data structure:

```
type Offerings = {
  current?: {
    availablePackages?: any[];
  }
};


export function hasValue<T>(value: T): value is NonNullable<T> {
  return value !== undefined && value !== null;
}

// ...

async function test() {
  const offerings: Offerings = await (await fetch('https://example.com')).json();

  if (offerings == null || offerings.current == null || offerings.current.availablePackages == null) {
    return;
  }

  if (!hasValue(offerings?.current?.availablePackages)) {
    return;
  }


  offerings.current.availablePackages.length < 1;
}
```

Now lets have a look at how TypeScript compiles those two checks:

```js
async function test() {
    var _a;
    const offerings = await (await fetch('https://example.com')).json();
    if (offerings == null || offerings.current == null || offerings.current.availablePackages == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (!hasValue((_a = offerings === null || offerings === void 0 ? void 0 : offerings.current) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.availablePackages)) {
        return;
    }

    offerings.current.availablePackages.length < 1;
}
```

I think by now you already see the difference. Your check happens in a two fold way. To pass a parameter to the `hasValue` function a temporary variable `_a` has been created. Since to access `availablePackages` with optional chaining, JavaScript checks for each property if it exists and otherwise safe guards the value.

So what ends up happening is that not your object gets passed to `hasValue` but a temporary variable created to implement the optional chaining feature itself.

The return of `hasValue` has therefore nothing to do with your actual object.
You will find that my added check works just fine, but of course it is more typing to do.

Once Javascript natively supports optional chaining in a broad market share, this behavior will surely change, because then TypeScript does not have to polyfill this behavior.